# Difference between pulling images and then running and just straight up running

Tags: docker

I am very interested in learning this mysterious Docker!
But I have this burning question that I can't simply do not understand from my point of view:

docker run [image]

AND

docker pull [image]

docker run [pulled_image]

So when you run an image that's locally not stored, Docker daemon pulls the image from Docker Hub and execute that image.

When you pull an image, Docker daemon pulls the image from Docker Hub and does not execute that image..:

[image: Docker Image]

What's the difference? When should I use one over another? Can you provide me with some examples! Thanks for your enlightenment! >3

Answer (score 0):

`docker pull` and `docker run` are commands used for different purposes.

- `docker pull <image_name>` will attempt to download the requested image from any declared registry(public or private). It will not start a container based on the downloaded image. It just downloads the image locally.
- `docker run` in the other hand will start a container from the declared image. If the image is not present locally, will perform internally a `docker pull` at first and then will start the container.

> When should I use one over another? Can you provide me with some
>   examples!

There is no rule on when to use one over the other. It depends on your requirements.

For example, if you need to run a container from a image not available locally, I would use `docker run` as it will fetch the image before processing a container. So I do not have to perform a `docker pull` by myself.

**Edit**(Thanks to @DavidMaze comment)
As for the `docker pull`, occasionally the image underneath a label changes (`ubuntu:18.04` gets security updates for instance) and in these cases it can be useful to manually docker pull an image to get the latest updates. Also note that `docker build`, like `docker run` can implicitly pull things. Manually pulling otherwise usually isn't necessary

References:

- [docker pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/)
- [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form)

Comment: Occasionally the image underneath a label changes (`ubuntu:18.04` gets security updates for instance) and in these cases it can be useful to manually `docker pull` an image.  Also note that `docker build`, like `docker run` can implicitly pull things.  Manually pulling otherwise usually isn't necessary.